# Formally coding finite combinatorics/number theory in Peano arithmetic

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

Thanks to Godel's lemma it is possible to 'code' a great deal of finite combinatorics and number theory within mathematics. How exactly do we do this? In particular, how do I make statements about functions and unordered (finite) sets in the language of $P\!A$?

For finite sets, I have seen a convention that we code them as sequences in increasing order. For example, I code the set $\{x_0,\ldots,x_{k-1}\}$ by $z$ where $z$ codes the sequence $(x_0,\ldots,x_{k-1})$, if $x_0<\cdots<x_{k-1}$; that is, $\beta(z,i)=x_i$ for all $i<k$, where $\beta$ is Godel's beta function.

How is this then implemented into formulae, do I need a formula $\psi(t)\leftrightarrow \text{'$t$ codes a finite set'}$? For example, if I wanted to say that every finite set from $N$ has a least element:
$$\forall n\big(\psi(n)\rightarrow \forall i\le n((n)_0\le(n)_i)\big),$$
where $(n)_i$ abbreviates $\beta(n,i)$.

As for functions, I code them with sets of ordered pairs (sequences of length two). $z$ codes a function from $X$ to $Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets of naturals) if $z$ is a finite set such that each element $x_i$ is an ordered pair where $(x_i)_0$ is in $X$ and $(x_i)_1$ is in $Y$. With my notation (mimicking my above attempt), this gets messy:
$$(\text{$z$ codes a function $f\colon X\to Y$})\leftrightarrow\psi(z)\wedge\forall i<\mathrm{len}(z)\big[
\\\mathrm{len}((z)_i)=2
\\\wedge\exists j<\mathrm{len}(X)\big(((z)_i)_0=(X)_j\big)
\\\wedge\exists j<\mathrm{len}(Y)\big(((z)_i)_1=(Y)_j\big)
\\\wedge\big(\forall j,k<\mathrm{len}(z)(((z)_j)_0=((z)_k)_0\rightarrow((z)_j)_1=((z)_k)_1)\big)\big],$$
where $\mathrm{len}(z)$ is the length of the sequence coded by $z$.

Am I along the right track? Any sources would be appreciated, I cannot find any examples of formalizing statements in $P\!A$!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's basically right. The details of Goedel coding (rather than Goedel's *lemma* - I'm not sure what lemma you refer to, but it's really the *definitions* here that are powerful) are dealt with in any good exposition of Goedel's theorem (e.g. [Peter Smith's book](http://www.logicmatters.net/igt/godel-without-tears/)), but they tend to use only what is needed - e.g. if they don't need to (say) use natural numbers to code finite Abelian groups, they won't show how this is done.

But you've hit on the right track. Basically:

- We know how to code finite *sets*.
- OK, great! Every other finite object we need in finite combinatorics/algebra/etc. is a *finite set with structure*, and these can always be viewed as a set of sets satisfying certain properties (you've only mentioned talking about *sets*, but we can also talk about *sets of sets* using the same idea, and sets of sets of sets, and so on). So no new ideas are needed here.

For example, let's look at Ramsey's theorem for pairs:

> For each $n$, there is some $k$ such that any two-coloring of the complete graph on $k$ vertices has a homogeneous set of size $n$.

Here's how we code this up.

- First, the set of edges of the complete graph on $k$ vertices is the set of two-element subsets of $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$.
- And a two-coloring of a graph can be represented as a subset of the edges (you're colored red if you're in the subset, and blue otherwise).
- So now we know how to say "For every two-coloring of the complete graph on $k$ vertices": this is just "For all sets of two-element sets of numbers $\le k$."
- Given a coloring $c$, a homogeneous set of size $n$ is a subset $S$ of $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$ such that $\vert S\vert=n$ and for each $a, b, c, d\in S$ with $a\not=b$ and $c\not=d$, we have $\{a,b\}\in S\iff \{c, d\}\in S$.
- There's nothing tricky here, so you know how to say "there is a homogeneous subset of size $n$."
- And now we're done! Putting together all the pieces we get an expression in the language of arithmetic which codes the statement "For each $n$, there is some $k$ such that every two-coloring of the complete graph on $k$ vertices has a homogeneous set of size $n$."

Note that this was all entirely routine: the point is that once you know how to code finite sets, coding other finite objects presents no difficulty.

---

Note that in this example, we had a number of choices. E.g. we represented a coloring as a single set, while it would arguably be more natural (but also more tedious) to represent it as a *partition* of the vertex set. Different choices lead to different codings, but that's fine: we only ever need *some* coding which "behaves well" (that is, such that PA proves the important facts about it - e.g. in the case of Goedel's theorem, we need the fact that if PA proves $\varphi$, then PA proves the *arithmetized statement* "PA proves $\varphi$", usually written "$\Box_{PA}\varphi$").

Answer (score 2):

As Noah has explained you are definitely on the right lines. An alternative approach to the technical details is to define a binary relation $\in_{\Bbb{N}}$ on natural numbers in the following way: if $n = \sum_{i=0}^k d_i2^i$ is the binary representation of $n$, with each $d_i \in \{0, 1\}$, then define $i \in_{\Bbb{N}} n$ iff $d_i = 1$. You can then define a mapping $E$ from natural numbers to sets by:

$$
E(n) = E\left( \sum_{i=0}^k d_i2^i\right) = \{ E(i) \mid d_i = 1\}
$$
(which is well-defined since we have $E(0) = \emptyset$ and the $E(i)$ that form the members of $E(n)$ have $i < n$).
$E$ is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between natural numbers and what are called the *hereditarily finite* sets: sets whose transitive closure is finite. Under this correspondence $i \in_{\Bbb{N}} n$ iff $E(i) \in E(n)$. The usual set-theoretic representation of any finite combinatorial problem can be constructed in the hereditarily finite sets and hence modelled using the relation $\in_{\Bbb{N}}$ on the natural numbers.

Using this representation, it can be shown that the the theory of arithmetic is equivalent to the theory of hereditarily finite sets. It can also be shown  that first-order Peano arithmetic (PA) is equivalent to Zermelo set theory  with the axiom of infinity replaced by the finite set induction principle which comprises the axioms:
$$
\phi(\emptyset) \land (\forall x {\cdot}\forall y {\cdot}(\phi(x) \Rightarrow \phi(x \cup \{y\})) \Rightarrow (\forall x {\cdot} \phi(x))
$$
for each formula $\phi(x)$ in the language of set theory. The finite set induction principle acts as a first-order approximation to the assertion that every set is finite just as the induction principle in PA acts as a first-order approximation to the assertion that every number is finite.

Comment: +1 - this is a great tool to use here, and the lemme is worth proving on its own and is not too hard.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: thanks for those encouraging words. I have tried to improve on my previously rather imprecise statement about the relations between first-order number theory and first-order finite set theory.